# "Treatment" of allergy.

Tags: autoimmune, immunity, allergies

Is there any treatment for allergy? I am not saying about solutions like epi-pen which reduce the symptoms. Is there any way to modify our immunity so that it does not identify the allergens? Can we modify our WBCs to not identify them?

Comment: See [Allergen immunotherapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allergen_immunotherapy) and eventually [Enzyme potentiated desensitization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enzyme_potentiated_desensitization).

Comment: @Remi.b in the article on EPD, there was this in mechanism section:- "The treatment uses dilutions of allergen and enzyme to which T-regulatory lymphocytes are believed to respond by favouring desensitization, or down-regulation, rather than sensitization. Once activated these lymphocytes travel to lymph nodes and reproduce or stimulate similar T-lymphocytes." What does it mean by "are believed to"? How does GIVING allergen desensitise T-lymphocytes?